# REGEX: Match everything except

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to achieve something relatively simple with RegEX but as I'm getting confused for over 3 hours, I was hoping you could help me.

Basically, I have a page with text inside, and many urls. I would like to remove everything in this page, except a specific domain.

Here's an example: https://regex101.com/r/sO6hX9/17 , I want to achieve the exactly same opposite, matching and removing all the rest, except https://my.domain.com/example/example?=12.

Here are my actual PHP patterns. I won't need them anymore as I changed my mind and now I want to parse only my domain:

```
           $patterns = array(
            '#<!-- [lmw] --><a class="postlink[^>]*>(.*<\/a[^>]*>)?<!-- [lmw] -->#Usi', // Magic URLs
            '#<[^>]*>(.*<[^>]*>)?#Usi', // HTML code
            '#\[/?[^\[\]]+\]#mi', // Strip all bbcode tags
            '#(https:\/\/my.domain.com\/[^\[\]\s]+)+#i', // Strip every https except my.domain.com occurrences
            '#(http|ftp|mailto)(:|\&\#58;)\/\/[^\s]+#i', // Strip remaining URLs
            '#"#', // Possible quotes from older board conversions
            '#[\s]+#' // Multiple spaces
        );
```

PHP function here: https://pastebin.com/2g5cR3WY

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/sO6hX9/18)?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, basically I want to the output to just be: https://my.domain.com/example/example?=12

Comment: You could use a negative look-around, but doing it with php is a lot easier.

Comment: Here's my PHP: https://pastebin.com/2g5cR3WY

Comment: So, you want to read a lot of text, match all domain links and then return only those matches stripping everything else?

Comment: Yes, exactly, there will usually be only one occurrence of that domain, if this can help.

Comment: Maybe you need https://ideone.com/YnhHqu?